# Android WebView change font size using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have some annoying problem while trying to set the font size inside the webview using javascript.

```
tvWebView.loadData(jsonObject.optString("body_1"), "text/html", "UTF-8");
    tvWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            tvWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(document.body.style.fontSize ='20pt');");
        }
    });
```

Instead of changing the font size I see the "20pt" string and nothing else inside the webview

Comment: Did you enabled javascript for webview?   `
getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 0):

get web setting and change font size.

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(20);
```